# When using image mapping and links i get delegated to mobile safari. Is there a way to stay in standalone mode with image map links

Tags: jquery, iphone, web

I am trying to simply user test a design and have image mapped the prototype images. They are simple PNGs of what the app may look like. Certain attributes of the design I would like to test before implementing tho.

Now I've used the answer:

```
    $(function() {
$('a').click(function() {
document.location = $(this).attr('href');
return false;
});


});
```

from above and changed the 'a' for 'img'. Also tried 'area' and 'map'. None of this worked. Would anyone have a clue about keeping me in standalone mode for this area mapping links?

Thanks a lot in advance